# setState loop seems to only run on the last iteration

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

So I have an app with friends and events, where each friends has specific events.
I just want to retrieve every single event from every single friend.
I have an 'event' *state* `const [events, setEvents] = useState([]);`
Then here is the problematic *useEffect* snippet:

```
useEffect(() => {
  getFriendsIds()
    .then(idsArray => {
      Promise.all(idsArray.map(id => {
        getUserEvents(id)
          .then(evs => {
            if (evs.length > 0) {
              for (let i=0; i<evs.length; i++) {
                setEvents([...events, evs[i]]);
              }
            }
          })
      }))
    })
}, [])
```

This should store the aforementioned events in the 'events' *state* variable.
However, when I try to render them with `{events.map(ev => renderItem(ev))}`, I only get the very last event of the last friend in the loop (It is guaranteed that renderItem works fine).
I would love an explanation of how this works, and if possible an alternative algorithm that actually achieves what I aim to do.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, this happens because your `useEffect()` doesn't have the `events` state in its dependency array.

```js
useEffect(() => {
   ...
}, [events])
```

However event this solution will not work properly because the `setState()` function works asynchronously.

You have to use state updater function in this case:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  ...
  setEvents((prevEvents) => [...prevEvents, evs[i]]);
  ...
}, []);
```

Read more about `dependency array` and `state updater` in the official documentation

Comment: Don't worry . This is a template comment we comment it to new contributors to help them discover StackOverflow community rules. Also, I will upvote your question as a push  keep asking questions, and don't forget to read: stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

Try passing a function to setEvents and remove the for loop.

```
if (evs.length > 0) {
    setEvents((prev) => ([...prev, ...evs]));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the `setState` out of the loop -

```js
useEffect(async () => {
  const ids = await getFriendsIds()
  const events = await Promise.all(ids.map(getUserEvents)))
  setEvents(events.flat())      // replace
}, [])
```

If you want to append `events` to the existing events state, you can use a functional update -

```js
useEffect(async () => {
  const ids = await getFriendsIds()
  const events = await Promise.all(ids.map(getUserEvents)))
  setEvents(r => [...r, ...events.flat()])    // append
}, [])
```

You can use `.flat` instead of checking for `.length` as it will remove empty arrays for you automatically -

```js
const a = [["event1", "event2"], [], ["event3"], ["event4"], []]

console.log(a.flat())
// ["event1", "event2", "event3", "event4" ]
```